# Development of SSRS reports using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I am developing some reports in SSRS (SQL Server 2008 R2). I have given application access by the client which has Visual Studio 2010 installed.

My Question:

- Can Visual Stuido 2010 (or 2008) be helpful in developing SQL Reports? if Yes, please guide.
- What are the prerequiesties required to develop a report through SSRS? I need to inform client about any required installation. Please Note: I would be developing reports through report builder (99% assured)
- Is SO the correct place to post this question or should i post in database site of Stack Exchange.

Please guide! Any Questions? Please respond.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop SSRS Reports you need to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) to create the .rdl files.

Sadly VS2010 can only create .rdlc files so you cant use VS2010 to develop reports to deploy to SSRS 2008.

The difference between these is that .rdl is a server controlled report and .rdlc is a client controlled report.

As for if VS2010 can be usefull, well you could write your SQL using it but I always just use Management Studio and BIDS 2008 or 2005.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Visual Studio 2010 to edit and deploy reports (.rdl). I don't know if there are differences which would not work once deployed but I tested a change to a previously made report (VS2008/SQL 2008 R2) and deployed it and it worked fine.

BIDS has also been renamed SQL Server Data Tools.

[Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333459/is-there-any-inbuilt-localization-resources-support-in-ssrs-using-visual-studio)